# Compiling PHP extension for windows

Tags: php, c, php-extension

I am trying to compile PHP-7.0.11 and a sample extension on Windows 8.1 using Visual Studio 2015. I am following https://wiki.php.net/internals/windows/stepbystepbuild. I have followed every step but still getting the following error:

```
{
    bison.exe --output=Zend/zend_language_parser.c -v -d -p zend Zend/zend_language_parser.y
    zend/zend_language_parser.y:49: unrecognized: %code
    zend/zend_language_parser.y:49:    Skipping to next %
    zend/zend_language_parser.y:52: unrecognized: %destructor
    zend/zend_language_parser.y:52:    Skipping to next %
    zend/zend_language_parser.y:53: unrecognized: %destructor
    zend/zend_language_parser.y:53:    Skipping to next %
    NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files\ux-utils\bison.exe"' : return code '0x1'
    Stop.
}
```

Also, I have noticed that `zend_language_parser.c` file is not generating in Zend directory.

Comment: `bison.exe` was already installed in my system and somehow while compiling, location was taken from system's directory instead of build directory. removing already installed `bison` solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This could also be because you have old version of **bison.exe**. I wanted to compile **php5.6** with **php-sdk-binary-tools-20110512** tools. which has version of bison that resulted in this error. Whereas **php-sdk-binary-tools-20110915** tooling has version **2.4.1** which perfectly compiles it.